# What is the key attribute in the table definition

Tags: mysql

What are these key attributes, I'm not able to search in the Mysql manual:

```
KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
      KEY `node_created` (`created`),
      KEY `node_moderate` (`moderate`),
      KEY `node_promote_status` (`promote`,`status`),
      KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
      KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
      KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
      KEY `uid` (`uid`),
      KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
      KEY `translate` (`translate`)
```

**full table structure is here:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `node` (
      `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
      `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL default '',
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `uid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `status` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
      `created` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `changed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `comment` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `promote` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `moderate` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      `translate` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`nid`),
      UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
      KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
      KEY `node_created` (`created`),
      KEY `node_moderate` (`moderate`),
      KEY `node_promote_status` (`promote`,`status`),
      KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
      KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
      KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
      KEY `uid` (`uid`),
      KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
      KEY `translate` (`translate`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1041 ;
```

Comment: *sigh* https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+key+attribute

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX.